# Why is the GLSL shader changing dark colors to green

Tags: glsl

This is my GLSL shader where input texture data.

```
vec3 ExtractColor(vec3 Color, float LumaMask)
{
    float Luma = dot(Color, vec3(1));
    float ColorMask = exp(-Luma * 2 * PI / LumaMask);
    Color = mix( Color, vec3(Luma), ColorMask);
    return vec3(Color / dot(Color, vec3(1.0)));                 
}
```

The issue i am facing is that when the color is very close to black or bright it gets converted to green color.

Answer (score 0):

here vec3(Luma) value is being used as the new color value so try the following.

change

```
Color = mix( Color, vec3(Luma), ColorMask);
```

to

```
Color = mix(Color, Color, ColorMask);
```